In what way do events imply a category of reality that is irreducible to substance?
Let's say that an event is a type of phenomenon such as smiles, walks, dances, weddings, hiccups, hand-waves, arrivals, departures, births, deaths, thunder, lightning, explosions, laughter, celebrations, gatherings, weeping, flashes of light, etc.
There are many ways to understand what the "essence" or "identity" (or absence) of an event is. I am not so interested in that aspect, but rather in what sense an event, or a specific way of understanding an event, necessarily implies a category or type of reality that is irreducible to being a "substance". That is: "why it is always the case that in every possible world is event ≠ substance?"
Substance means: (D1) an object with a set of properties or characteristics (i.e., a tree with weight, color, size...); (D2) an irreducible element (principle) of reality that hierarchically explains everything else; (D3) an underlying object in which a set of properties inhere (if you have a better and more synthetic systematization of the idea of substance, I’m all ears).
In my opinion, events are not substances since they do not share any characteristics of the three definitions, although (if these exist) they can comprise a set of substances within them.
Is there any philosopher who proves that events cannot, under any concept, be substances?
Thank you in advance.

In Whitehead’s framework everything is process, substances are just stages in ongoing processes. What might appear as a substance is simply an abstraction from a more fundamental event or process, not unlike Hume's bundle theory or object oriented programming, which directly argues against the reducibility of localized temporal-only feature placed functorized events to perdurant substances...

@Conifold Thank you, this clears some things up for me.

Can you first say how that Question differs from 'In what way do events imply reality is irreducible to substance?'

From Conifold:

Philosophical uses of "substance" are described in SEP, Substance and there are two main senses, broad and narrow. In the narrow sense, substances are the cores of objects that endure through change, in contradistinction to events, properties and relations. So they are distinct from events by definition. In the broad sense, substances are fundamental entities of an ontology. So events will be substances in event-based ontologies (as in versions of process philosophy), again by definition.


I believe that the essence of something can be possible without the existence of its building blocks. The building block must be itself. When we examine an event, we tend to think of the components that make up that event. For example, you might consider the components of the event 8 to be 3 and 5. However, someone else could tell you that 6 and 2 are also building blocks or components of that event. Therefore, the components of an event can be divided infinitely. Being infinitely divisible suggests that one event cannot be a part of another event. Ultimately, all events in the world are a whole, and thus they constitute a single event. I call this single event the essence.

The argument between Substance Ontology and Process Ontology is as old as the history of philosophy.
You won't find anything resembling an ironclad refutation of one by the other anywhere. There are plenty of attempts (see the Criticisms section of the first link). But ultimately ontological commitments are not conclusions or claims, they're ways of thinking about things and verbalizing descriptions. You can argue that a way of thinking about and describing things is more or less useful. But a way of thinking about and describing things is not a conclusion, so you can't refute it.

Anyone would say that your response is proof of what you're saying!
